# how to save checkbox status in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have 100 to do check boxes, I wanted to save their status. So after relaunch the value should be there.
Is there any Simple Way.

below is the thing on which I'm working currently.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
}
//State is information of the application that can change over time or when some actions are taken.
class _State extends State<MyApp>{

  bool _value1 = false;
  bool _value2 = false;

  //we omitted the brackets '{}' and are using fat arrow '=>' instead, this is dart syntax
  void _value1Changed(bool value) => setState(() => _value1 = value);
  void _value2Changed(bool value) => setState(() => _value2 = value);

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Name here'),
      ),
      //hit Ctrl+space in intellij to know what are the options you can use in flutter widgets
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new CheckboxListTile(
                  value: _value2,
                  onChanged: _value2Changed,
                  title: new Text('Check box 1'),
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  subtitle: new Text('100th'),
                  secondary: new Icon(Icons.archive),
                  activeColor: Colors.red,
              ),

              new CheckboxListTile(
                  value: _value2,
                  onChanged: _value2Changed,
                  title: new Text('Check box 2'),
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  subtitle: new Text('99th'),
                  secondary: new Icon(Icons.archive),
                  activeColor: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Comment: you can use this package : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: thanks for ur help